# Setup Kamailio to accept only register request with FQDN and block IP request

Tags: proxy, asterisk, sip

I have set up Kamailio and am quite new to the process, I'm able to register with FQDN and IP directly to Kamailio but my main setup is Kamailio as edge proxy to asterisk to allow register only with FQDN and not IP,

route {
if (!is_domain("$hdr(Contact:user)")) {
sl_send_reply("403", "Forbidden");
exit;
}
t_relay();
}
I found this and implemented it on kamailio.cfg but not working, Appreciate to help point me in the right direction.